# What is the command for evaluating definite integral using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What is the command for evaluating definite integral of the function `f(x)=exp(-ikx)exp(sin x)` from `-pi to pi` for`k=-10, -9, ........, 10` in MATLAB using chebfun system?
I know how to find a definite integral for a particular value of k but I want the command lines for evaluating the values of the integral for the above values of k at a stretch.

Comment: Could you show us the code you already have to calculate one particular integral? That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: f=chebfun('exp(10*sqrt(-1)*x).*exp(sin(x))',[-pi pi]);
plot(f);
sum(f)